# Clip images from other websites and add it to my website

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

To clip images from other websites i have used Bookmarklet.
I got success in displaying images and selecting images but while storing it on my webserver i am getting the cross-domain error.The error is as follows:

Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {// The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced' return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );} has no method 'closePopupMenu'

Thanks in advance

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: How to create a clipper that lists images of currently opened webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
// Obtain HTML from a website
$.get("http://www.google.com", function(data) {
    // Extract every img tag from the complete HTML
    $('img', data).each(function() {
        // Extract the src attribute from every IMG
        alert($(this).attr('src'));
    });
}).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {   
    alert("error: "+textStatus); 
});
```

Comment: i have to add clipper in bookmark.so when user visit any site and if he/she wants to get images of that particular page then he will click that bookmarked link and all the images will be displayed in a popup.

Comment: http://www.zarctech.com/image/PolyvoreClipper.JPG 
please see this image for a reference.
or you can go to polyvore.com and check it too.